# Tomar el texto de un archivo plano (Archivo.txt) y guardarlo en un string

Tags: java

Como dice el titulo quisiera ayuda para poder tomar el texto de "x" archivo y guardarlo en un string para poder recorrerlo caracter por caracter.

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

### Leer todo el texto de un archivo

Acá te dejo una rutina compacta para Java 7, envuelta en un método utilitario:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

### Leer líneas de texto de un archivo

Java 7 añadió un [método para leer un archivo como líneas de texto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) representadas en un `List<String>`. Este enfoque pierde información ya que los separadores de línea son eliminados de cada una de ellas.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```

### Utilización de memoria

El primer método, que conserva los separadores de línea puede requerir temporalmente memoria varias veces el tamaño del archivo, debido a que, por un corto período de tiempo, el contenido plano del archivo (un arreglo de bytes), y los caracteres decodificados (cada uno ocupando 16 bits aún cuando la codificación sea de 8 bits en el fichero) residen en memoria a la vez. Es más seguro aplicarlo a archivos que se sabe de antemano que son pequeños en relación a la memoria disponible.

El segundo método, que lee líneas, es usualmente más eficiente en el uso de memoria, ya que el buffer de entrada para decodificar no contiene el archivo completo. Sin embargo, tampoco es recomendable para archivos que son muy grandes relativos a la memoria disponible.

Para leer archivos grandes, se necesita diseñar el programa de manera diferente. Leer un trozo de texto del stream, procesarla, y luego moverse al siguiente trozo, reutilizando un bloque de memoria de tamaño constante. Aquí, "grande" depende de las especificaciones del equipo. En estos días, este límite puede estar en el orden de los Gibabytes de RAM.

### Codificación de caracteres

Hay casos especiales donde el default de la plataforma es justamente lo que quieres, pero hay otros donde necesitas el poder de elegir.

La clase [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) define algunas constantes para las codificaciones, requeridas para todos los runtime de Java.

```
String content = readFile("test.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

El defualt de la plataforma se encuentra disponible en la [clase `Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29)  misma:

```
String content = readFile("test.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
```

<sub>Con información de [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)</sub>

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas, logre solucionar el problema!

Comment: Enhorabuena @Lorenzo, si te ha funcionado, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros usuarios sabrán que ha sido correcta para ti. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 7+**

```
Path path = Paths.get("directorio", "archivo.txt");
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

lines.forEach(line -> builder.append(line));
return builder.toString();
```